# Find a matrix such that the systems are equivalent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Take the system

$\begin{cases}
w=v'\\
v''-\mu v'+v=0
\end{cases}$

for $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$

Find a constant matrix $A^{\mu}$ such that the above system is equivalent to

$\begin{bmatrix}v'\\w'\end{bmatrix}=A^{\mu}\begin{bmatrix}v'\\w'\end{bmatrix}$

My first thought was to find a solution to $v''-\mu v'+v=0$. Taking the characteristic polynomial as $r^2-\mu r+1=0$, I get $r=\frac{1}{2}(\mu \pm\sqrt{\mu^2-4})$. Not really sure what to do at this point, however. Another way to solve this might be first to replace $v'$ in the second equation with $w$ to get $v''-\mu w+v=0$ but I'm not sure where to go from there either.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming here that you meant $\begin{bmatrix}v'\\w'\end{bmatrix}=A^{\mu}\begin{bmatrix}v\\w\end{bmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix}v'\\w'\end{bmatrix}=A^{\mu}\begin{bmatrix}v'\\w'\end{bmatrix}$; in the latter case, $A^\mu$ would just be the identity matrix.)

If you replace $v'$ with $w$ in the second line of your equation and isolate each equation for $v'$ and $w'$, you get:

$\begin{cases}
v'=w\\
w'=-v + \mu w
\end{cases}$

Now all you have to do is find a matrix of coefficients $a$ through $d$ such that:

$$\begin{bmatrix}v'\\w'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v\\w\end{bmatrix}$$

For this matrix to correspond to your set of equations, it must be the case that $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $c = -1$, and $d = \mu$.